# shallow copy of ConcurrentBag to a non concurrent collection in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures

Is there a non-concurrent analogy to ConcurrentBag in C#? I need to create a snapshot of a concurrentBag so I need a shallow copy and I don't need thread safety. Note that concurrentbag  can contain duplicates.

thanks

Comment: `ToArray()` or `ToList` will do the trick, as both lists and arrays allow duplicates.

Comment: although not a perfect analog, that works fine.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a closer analog would be to create a `Queue<T>`, since it supports taking (the `Dequeue` method).

```
ConcurrentBag<MyType> bag = new ConcurrentBag<MyType>();

// create a queue
Queue<MyType> q = new Queue<MyType>(bag);
```